# How do I prevent JQuery animate calls from getting queued up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Background**

I am working on a project that relies heavily on JQuery .animate(), it occasionally receives external updates via Socket.io that call animate(). When the window is open, everything runs fine and animate calls can run asynchronously.

**Problem**

However, when the browser is minimized or a different tab is open then reopened, all the animations that should have been run while it was closed are queued up and run in that they were received.

*Here is the animate call:*

```
$(div).animate({
  'top': this.topPos(),
  'right': this.rightPos()
}, 100);
```

Is there a simple way to add on option to the animate() call or call some jquery function or should I just add the appropriate logic to the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`.stop(true,true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) by passing `true` as both parameters

```
.stop( [clearQueue], [jumpToEnd] )

clearQueue: A Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to false.

jumpToEnd:  A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.
```

in your example it will be applied like:

```
$(div).stop(true,true).animate({
  'top': this.topPos(),
  'right': this.rightPos()
}, 100);
```

Comment: -1 I'm sorry but as useful as .stop(true, true) is, as @rick states, its due to requestAnimationFrame being usesd in jQuery that caused the problem.

Comment: why i am getting DV on this answer care to explain

Comment: @Tomgrohl another answer being correct doesn't mean this is not correct

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to agree with @Rick. There's a bug filed on jQuery about what is mentioned in the question. This is the reason for the problem.

Comment: @3nigma Your answer provides a potentially feasible work-around, but is still an incorrect assessment of what caused this problem in jQuery.

Comment: @3nigma in 2012, operating on the newest version of jQuery, your answer was still the only one who solved my problem, +1 and a huge thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour was caused by the introduction of `requestAnimationFrame`, which has been removed as of jQuery 1.6.3rc1 (released yesterday).

See also: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9381

Answer (score 1):

You can call `stop()` on the element being animated before you call `animate()` again. Like this:

```
$(div).stop().animate({
  'top': this.topPos(),
  'right': this.rightPos()
}, 100);
```

It will stop the animations being queued up and fired in one go.

See [here for details of `stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Hope this helps.